# roman to integer leetcode in C fails for MCMXCIV

Tags: c, roman-numerals

The last test case of `s = "MCMXCIV"` is not working. the output is `3099` instead of `1994`. I have added all the roman numerals to integers and can't figure out where the issue is. The first two cases were properly executed to give expected output.

```
// code start
int romanToInt(char *s) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (*s == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == 'M') {
            sum = sum + 1000;
        }
        if (s[i] == 'D') {
            sum = sum + 500;
        }
        if (s[i] == 'C') {
            sum = sum + 100;
        }
        if (s[i] == 'L') {
            sum = sum + 50;
        }
        if (s[i] == 'X') {
            sum = sum + 10;
        }
        if (s[i] == 'V') {
            sum = sum + 5;
        }
        if (s[i] == 'I') {
            sum = sum + 1;
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            if (s[i] == 'V' && s[i - 1] == 'I') {
                sum = sum + 3;
            }
            if (s[i] == 'X' && s[i - 1] == 'I') {
                sum = sum + 8;
            }
            if (s[i] == 'L' && s[i - 1] == 'X') {
                sum = sum + 30;
            }
            if (s[i] == 'C' && s[i - 1] == 'X') {
                sum = sum + 80;
            }
            if (s[i] == 'D' && s[i - 1] == 'C') {
                sum = sum + 300;
            }
            if (s[i] == 'M' && s[i - 1] == 'C') {
                sum = sum + 800;
            }
        }
        //sum represents the converted integer
    }
    return sum;
}//code end
```

Comment: https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-convert-roman-number-decimal-number/

Comment: Try something simple like `MCM`. You'd add 1000, then 100, then 1000 _and_ 800.

Comment: For such challenges, I suggest you make some test cases yourself and use a debugger. After all, the challenge is that *you* solve the problem. Do you have a question about C?

Comment: Even just `IV` should serve as a test case. You add 1, then you add 5, then you add 3.

Comment: But in general, just print the sum each loop iteration and you'll see where it starts going wrong.

Comment: The condition `*s==NULL` is wrong. The expression `*s` is exactly the same as `s[0]`, which means you might dereference a null-pointer. I suspect you wanted to write `s == NULL` instead? Also, you return `NULL` which is the null pointer, not the integer value `0`.

Comment: It seems like you have little understanding about how roman numbers work, so I suggest you start from there. It's not just a little mistake in your code.

Comment: There is no subtraction in the code. If a Roman digit precedes a higher one, it is subtracted.

Comment: Hint: Test for "CM" to add 900 and skip TWO characters. Apply this to other combinations of lower then higher roman "digits".

Comment: I was able to make changes and the code works. Appreciate the help.

Comment: FWIW, your basic idea is workable. It's just a matter of putting the `if` statements in the correct order, and making sure that only one of the `if` statements is executed. Glad to hear that you were able to make it work.

Comment: There is a codegolf on this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/797/186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- comparing `*s` to `NULL` is incorrect: `NULL` is a macro representing a null pointer, `*s` is not a pointer, it is a character, which you can compare to `'\0'` or `0` instead.  Your code compiles by chance if `NULL` is defined as `0` or `0L` but would not for the alternative classic definition `((void *)0)`.
- this initial test is useless anyway as the `for` loop will stop immediately for an empty string.
- the test `i < strlen(s)` may recompute the string length at each iteration, which is inefficient. You could just test if `s[i] != '\0'`.
- the rule for roman numerals is simple: if a letter value is less than that of the next letter, its value is subtracted from the value of the next one.

Here is a modified version:

```
int romanDigit(char c) {
    switch (c) {
      case 'I': return 1;
      case 'V': return 5;
      case 'X': return 10;
      case 'L': return 50;
      case 'C': return 100;
      case 'D': return 500;
      case 'M': return 1000;
      default: return 0;
    }
}

int romanToInt(const char *s) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (*s) {
        int digit = romanDigit(*s++);
        int next = romanDigit(*s);
        if (digit && digit < next) {
            sum += next - digit;
            s++;
        } else {
            sum += digit;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This simplistic implementation works for `MCMXCIV` (`1994`) but does not detect invalid numbers such as `MXMIV`, `MVMI`, `XMMIV`... which will be all produce `1994` as well.  The classic representations only use `I`, `X` and `C` in front of the next 2 letters, but many variations have been found throughout the long history of [Roman Numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals).

Roman numerals embody one of the most durable human inventions of all time: counting. The shape of the letters `I`, `V` and `X` look amazingly similar to [Tally marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_marks) found on prehistoric artifacts.  It gives me the chills to see in the most scientifically advanced publications the very shapes used by stone age cavemen to count.

Comment: *"comparing *s to NULL is incorrect"* - It's ugly, but `0 == NULL` will evaluate to true.

Comment: @klutt: I shall rephrase this part: it works by coincidence if `NULL` is defined as `0` or `0L` but would not for the alternative classic definition `((void *)0)`. `0 == NULL` always works, but `*s == NULL` might not.

Comment: Why would not `*s == NULL` work? The string ends when `*s == 0`, so in practice it is the same as `0 == NULL`? (Note that I agree that it is bad style)

Comment: @klutt: because on systems where `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)`, the code `*s == ((void *)0)` should at least generate a warning.

Comment: Why? The standard says that `0 == NULL` should evaluate to true. So if `*s` is `0` then `*s == NULL` should also evaluate to true.

Comment: Or was it the other way around? That the standard says that `T *p = 0;` will create a null pointer? And maybe that does not translate to what I said?

Comment: @klutt: Here is the language of the C Standard, **6.5.9 Equality operators**  **Constraints**
*2 One of the following shall hold:
— both operands have arithmetic type;
— both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
— one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`; or
— one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.* `*s` is not a null pointer constant even if it is a null character.  `*s == NULL` is a constraint violation if `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)`.

Comment: I was thinking about this from the standard "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant or a value of the type nullptr_t (which is necessarily the value nullptr) is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function."*

Comment: @klutt: indeed that's the definition of a *null pointer*, but `*s` is not an *integer constant expression*.

Comment: Hmmm, if I understand it correctly, the comparison `*s == NULL` will work correctly when `*s` is zero, but not when it's something else?

Comment: @klutt: not exactly: **if** the macro `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)` the expression `*s == NULL` is a **constraint violation**, hence the compiler should issue a warning, possibly an error, and whatever code is produced does not have a behavior defined by the standard.  The C Standard just specifies that `NULL` *expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant*.  Common implementations are `#define NULL 0` (systems where pointers and `int` have the same size), `#define NULL 0L` (systems where `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(long)`), `#define NULL ((void*)0)` (works on all systems).

Comment: Fair enough [padding]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly simple program to do it. Note that it does not check for invalid strings. But it has a much cleaner design and separates the actual roman values from the logic of calculating them.

It utilizes these rules:

- Repeating numbers adds to each other
- A smaller number followed by a bigger means subtraction
- When any of above is done, calculate the result and add with the rest

It does NOT follow these rules

- D, L and V cannot be repeated
- No letter can be repeated more than 3 times
- Subtractable letters are I, X or C
- Subtraction must be made with the largest subtractable letter

And possibly a few other rules that I did not implement.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int val(char c) {
    switch(c) {
    case 'M': return 1000;
    case 'D': return 500;
    case 'C': return 100;
    case 'L': return 50;
    case 'X': return 10;
    case 'V': return 5;
    case 'I': return 1; 
    default: return 0; // To make base case work
    }   
}

int roman(char *s) {
    char cur = *s;

    // Base case
    if(cur == 0) return 0;

    // Subtraction like IX
    char next = s[1];
    int diff = val(next) - val(cur);
    if(diff > 0) return diff + roman(&s[2]);

    // This takes care of repeating numbers, or just continues
    return val(cur) + roman(&s[1]);;
}
 
void printRoman(char *s) {
    printf("%s = %d\n", s, roman(s));
}
 
int main(void) {
    printRoman("M");
    printRoman("MM");
    printRoman("MMM");
    printRoman("MMMCM");
    printRoman("IV");
    printRoman("MCMXCIV");
}
```

Output:

```
M = 1000
MM = 2000
MMM = 3000
MMMCM = 3900
IV = 4
MCMXCIV = 1994
```

https://onlinegdb.com/poJLQy70C

Answer (score 1):

Following the OP method of using a cascade of `if()` statements, there's the following. (Notice the absence of unnecessary curly braces, and the use of C's comma operator.) This makes use of C's 'pairing' an `else` with the "last else-less `if`".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int romanToInt( char *s ) {
    int sum = 0;

    for( size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++ ) {
        char d = s[i], n = s[i+1]; // this 'd'igit and the 'n'ext...
        int v = 0;

             if( d == 'M' )     v = 1000;
        else if( d == 'D' )     v = 500;
        else if( d == 'C' )
                 if( n == 'M' ) v = 900, i++; // "CM" is two chars meaning 900
            else if( n == 'D' ) v = 400, i++; // ... and so on.
            else                v = 100;
        else if( d == 'L' )     v = 50;
        else if( d == 'X' )
                 if( n == 'C' ) v = 90, i++;
            else if( n == 'L' ) v = 40, i++;
            else                v = 10;
        else if( d == 'V' )     v = 5;
        else if( d == 'I' )
                 if( n == 'X' ) v = 9, i++;
            else if( n == 'V' ) v = 4, i++;
            else                v = 1;

        sum += v;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main( void ) {
    char *test[] = { "MCMXCIV", "MMXXIII", "MCDXCII" };

    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof test/sizeof test[0]; i++ )
        printf( "%d: %s - %d\n", i, test[i], romanToInt( test[i] ) );

    return 0;
}
```

```
0: MCMXCIV - 1994
1: MMXXIII - 2023
2: MCDXCII - 1492
```

No effort has been made to ensure the source string is a valid Roman Numeral.

---

**EDIT:**
On the other hand, interweaving data and processing can lead to headaches.

For a conversion like this, a well thought out *lookup table* storing the mappings can be served by a tiny bit of code (such as the following.)

```
int romanToInt( char *ps ) {
    struct { int v; char *s; } rnc[] = {
        { 1000, "M"  }, {  900, "CM" }, {  500, "D"  }, {  400, "CD" },
        {  100, "C"  }, {   90, "XC" }, {   50, "L"  }, {   40, "XL" },
        {   10, "X"  }, {    9, "IX" }, {    5, "V"  }, {    4, "IV" },
        {    1, "I"  },
    }, *p = rnc;

    int val = 0;

    while( *ps )
        if( ( p->s[0] == ps[0] ) && ( p->s[1] == '\0' || p->s[1] == ps[1] ) )
            val += p->v, ps += 1 + (p->s[1] != '\0');
        else
            p++;

    return val;
}
```

---

**EDIT2:**
A curly brace aficionado appears to dislike this answer.

In response, here is the previous version modified to check and reject invalid Roman Numerals... Easy maintenance when the design is already sound:

```
int romanToInt( char *ps ) {
    struct { int v; char *s; int skip; } rnc[] = {
        { 1000, "M", 0 }, {  900, "CM", 4 }, {  500, "D", 2  }, {  400, "CD", 2 },
        {  100, "C", 0 }, {   90, "XC", 4 }, {   50, "L", 2  }, {   40, "XL", 2 },
        {   10, "X", 0 }, {    9, "IX", 4 }, {    5, "V", 2  }, {    4, "IV", 2 },
        {    1, "I", 0  },
    }, *p = rnc;

    int val = 0, cnt = 0;

    while( *ps && val >= 0 && p < sizeof rnc/sizeof rnc[0] )
        if( ( p->s[0] == ps[0] ) && ( p->s[1] == '\0' || p->s[1] == ps[1] ) )
            if( ++cnt > (p-skip ? 1 : 3) ) // Disallow some multiples
                val = -1;
            else
                val += p->v, // add the value
                ps += 1 + (p->s[1] != '\0'), // skip 1 or 2 chars of input
                p += p->skip, // advance to next(?) allowable substring
                cnt = p->skip ? 0 : cnt; // reset counter (if needed)
        else
            if( ++p > rnc + 12 )
                val = -1;
            else
                cnt = 0;

    return val;
}

int main( void ) {
    char *test[] = {
        "MCMXCIV", "MMXXIII", "MCDXCII", // all good
        "MCDCDXCII", "MCDXCCCCII", // both bad
        "III", "IIII" // good and bad
    };

    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof test/sizeof test[0]; i++ )
        printf( "%15s ==> %4d\n", test[i], romanToInt( test[i] ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
        MCMXCIV ==> 1994
        MMXXIII ==> 2023
        MCDXCII ==> 1492
      MCDCDXCII ==>   -1
     MCDXCCCCII ==>   -1
            III ==>    3
           IIII ==>   -1
```

Comment: "unnecessary curly braces" is a style issue - some favor `{}`, some not.  As is here, code becomes unclear when auto-formatting applied.  Code that does not well autoformat is higher maintenance. OTOH, interesting `if( n == ...)` construct.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Coming from the age when XLII was the answer to most things, I find autoformat comparable to the dreaded "autocomplete"... I like it when my mistakes are made by me, not automation... :-) (This "style" of if/else indent does make 'scanning/comparing' easier, imho :-) Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: "I like it when my mistakes are made by me, not automation." is an OK approach for personal code.  For group efforts of many folks over years, auto-formatting is the cost effective solution.  I like my formatting more than auto-formatting, yet it is not worth the time for a group or even myself.  IAC, how to format should be driven by the group's coding standards.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "When in Rome, do as the Romans do..." Very appropriate! `:-)`

Comment: I do like how this looks, but when code is manually formatted like this it's hell to maintain.

Comment: @klutt Have posted another version that may appeal. Still a bit of a finger in the pie for formatting, but it has brevity on its side. Once a mapping function is written and fully tested, maintenance shouldn't be an issue (for 2000 year old number systems :-)

Comment: Hmmm, one part of me really dislike having two letter numbers in the lookup table since that can be solved with logic, but I have to admit that it's not such a bad choice since it makes the logic A LOT easier. Whatever gets the job done I guess.

Comment: But while I'm on your side with that you don't always need curly braces, I'm really scared of those commas. Feels like the accident is just waiting around the corner. :)

Comment: @klutt DV bothers me, so I added a version to detect/reject invalid Roman Numerals... Maintenance isn't the issue some seem to think it is... `:-)`

Comment: I might add that I did not DV

Comment: *"Maintenance isn't the issue some seem to think it is..."* - Famous last words :D

Answer (score 0):

Your basic approach is solid, but your conditions are not in the proper order, and you likely want to use `else` to ensure only one branch can execute. As characters are integral, you can use a switch statement.

You can then check if you're on the first character and `continue` to skip control flow over the remainder of the loop where you check the preceding character and go straight to the next iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    switch (s[i]) {
        case 'M':
        sum += 1000;
        break;

        case 'D':
        sum += 500;
        break;

        case 'C':
        sum += 100;
        break;
 
        case 'L': 
        sum += 50;
        break;
       
        case 'X':
        sum += 10;
        break;
     
        case 'V':
        sum += 5;
        break;
  
        case 'I':
        sum += 1;
        break; 
    }

    if (i == 0) continue;

    if (s[i] == 'M' && s[i-1] == 'C') 
        sum -= 100;
    else if (s[i] == 'V' && s[i-1] == 'I')
        sum -= 1;
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: I was operating under the assumption that the program did not require determining whether a Roman numeral was valid or not. If it does, then yes, you'd need code to determine that "CCM" is not valid.

Comment: I thought wrong

Comment: Happens to the best of us.